# After each 2 digits put / automatically in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm using oracle 10g forms and want to make a parameter form, there is an `item_code` field format of it is e.g **`01/02/03/0032`**.

So I want to make in the form field that after **01** forward-slash (**/**) should come auto then after next **02** again slash (**/**) should come auto.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set format mask `99g99g99g99g99` with `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='./'`:

```
select
 to_char(
    123456789,
    '99g99g99g99g99', 
    'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''./'''
 ) val
from dual
```

It will give you `1/23/45/67/89`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Forms itself can't do that - you'll need some kind of Java (i.e. **Java Beans**).

I don't know anything about it (nor have I ever used Java Beans), but - see [Francois Degrelle's blog](http://fdegrelle.over-blog.com/page/6), he knows *a lot* about it.